# Working with Outlook 365 on an windows enviroment

Tags: visual-studio-2012, outlook, office365

I know it's a general question.

I am trying to create an application/extension that reads the contents of an email before it is sent out. So basically if the email contains a 8 character numerical for example, it will prompt an alert box whether the employee is sure before it is sent out.

I have worked with some Python outlook modules for myself. But my task would for it to be able to run on most employee desktops which wouldn't have Python installed.

I am looking at tools such as Visual Studio but am unsure where I should start.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop a VBA macro or Outlook COM add-in (for example, VSTO based one) for that. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly.

Basically you need to handle the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

For example, here is a VBA sample code:

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application  

Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
  Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application  
End Sub 

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)  
  Dim prompt As String  
  prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"  
  If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then  
     Cancel = True  
  End If  
End Sub
```

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.